# Parsing vector<string> into a string

Tags: c++, string, vector, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize a string. The strings I'm working on have the following format:

```
name,city,major,color,hobbies,age.
```

I'm using the code below to do that. And temp is a string.

```
    cin>>command;
    vector <string> tokens;
    stringstream check(command);
    string middle;
    while(getline(check, intermediate, ','))
    {
        tokens.push_back(intermidiate);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<tokens.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << tokens[i] <<endl;

    }
    temp = tokens[1];
    cout<<temp;
```

And I'm trying to *parse* the vector of string into just a string, but my program crashes when I tried to do that...

Is there a way to parse it into just a string or should I try something else entirely?

Comment: You don't show any code that "parses"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't check if you access a valid element in the vector.  So it's probable that you go out of bounds.  To prevent this replace the end of your code with:

```
cout << tokens.size() << " elements:"<<endl;
if (tokens.size()>1)
    temp = tokens[1];
else temp = "Second element not found";
cout<<temp;
```

Also, the way you read command will stop reading at the first space separator:

```
cin>>command;    //entering "hello world" would cause command to be "hello"
```

In order to be sure that your string is not shortened in this unexpected fashion, you could consider using `getline()` instead:

```
getline (cin,command);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/DO22nF)

**Note:** the terme *parse* is misleading. I understood that you want to extract just one specific value of the array.  But if you want to concatenate several vector elements into a single string, you need to do a little more.

```
string tmp; 
for (auto const& x:tokens)
    tmp += x+" ";
cout << tmp<<endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, and I appreciate the explanation now I understand what i was doing wrong!